# No such file and directory found Xcode 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7

I embedded evernote SDK into my application but it was not working. Therefore, I decided to delete it from my code and removed all related frameworks and everything but after building my application, it is my code still tries to refer evernote SDK folder. I checked my "Copy Bundle Resources" and "Link Binaries with Libraries". Everything seems Okay. I want to remove this error without adding evernote SDK folder.

[image]

Help me please?

Comment: Trying cleaning the build folder. Drop Down the product menu and hold down ALT and Clean will change to clean the build folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try doing following:

1. Product -> Clean and build folder
2. Go to finder -> library -> Developer -> Xcode -> Derived data delete
   that folder

Also, see if evernote SDK was ever linked to your test target. If so, you would need to delete if from there as well.

Comment: Not working, I deleted the test folder and also checked my test target.

Comment: And you double checked your project and test targets `Copy Bundle Resources` for any red files?

Comment: Yes. There are no red files.

Comment: Thanks, evernote SDK was hidden in another folder. It is working now.

Answer (score 2):

1. Trying cleaning the build folder. Drop Down the product menu and hold down ALT and Clean will change to clean the build folder.
2. Check **Build Settings** Linking section.
3. Check **Build Phases** Link Binary with Binaries section and Copy Bundle Resources section.

Answer (score 2):

GoTo Build Phase > Search missing framework name > you will see same framework name also available on ***Copy Bundle Resources*** remove this framework from here > Done

I had the same issue after this process working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like as part of build, you have a step to copy that particular SDK and it's no longer there. You need to edit your build steps.

Comment: I know this solution but do not want to do this because I was trying to link evernote SDK and there was an error. Therefore, I want to remove evernote SDK and all links and try this process again.